# pycairo set center point of rotation

Tags: python, 2d, cairo, pycairo

I am using pycairo to do some drawing.

I am using the context rotate method to rotate the context before I draw on it....as described [here.](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/context.html#)

This rotates the context around the point of 0,0. I would like to rotate around the center of the image. So I have defined the surface to be 1000,1000, so I would like the center point of rotation to be 500,500. Is this easily possible with pycairo?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463271/rotate-text-around-its-center-in-pycairo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rotate text around its center in pycairo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463271/rotate-text-around-its-center-in-pycairo)